# Logstash grok pattern field not appearing in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, logstash-grok

I have recently been investigating ELK as a potential logging/monitoring solution. I have the stack set up and working, and I am starting to filter logs via grok.

Is it possible to have a specific part of your grok pattern appear as a field in Kibana?

For example, take the following pattern:

```
SAMSLOG %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} \[%{USERNAME:user}\] - %{JAVALOGMESSAGE}
```

I was hoping (and from what I have read) "user" should become an available field in Kibana that I am able to search/filter the results on? Have I completely misunderstood or am I missing a vital link in the chain?

Full Grok pattern:

```
multiline {
      patterns_dir => "/home/samuel/logstash/grok.patterns"
      pattern => "(^%{SAMSLOG})"
      negate => true
      what => "previous"
    }
```

Thank you,
Sam

Comment: provide your log sample

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the whole "magic" of logstash is to take the unstructured data and make structured fields from it.  So, your basic premise is correct.

What you're missing is that multiline{} is a filter that is used to combine several input lines into one event; that's basically all it does.  The "pattern" field there is used to identify when a new line should be started.

To make fields out of an event, you would need to use the grok{} filter.